# Last Date Required from More Date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have Three Table

T1 have

```
Item  QTY  
A1     10    
B1     15
```

T2

```
TxnID  Date  
T1     04/04/2013  
T2     05/05/2013  
T3     06/06/2013  
T4     07/07/2013  
T5     08/08/2013
```

T3

```
Item TxnID        QTY  
A1   04/04/2013   2  
B1   05/05/2013   3  
A1   06/06/2013   2  
B1   07/07/2013   3
```

I want to find out max date against Item

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: have  you tried anything if yes then put up the query here and moreover i think in table "T3" Txnid will be T1 , T2 , T3 , T4 not the dates right ???

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table "T3" Txnid will be T1 , T2 , T3 , T4 not the dates .. I think you need follwing

```
Select T1.Item , Max(T2.Date) From T1 , T2 , T3 Where T1.Item = T3.Item And T3.TxnID = T2.TxnID
Group by T1.Item
```

Answer (score 0):

The query to get the maximum date for an item (assuming you really have an item id in the third table):

```
select t3.item, max(t2.date)
from t2 join
     t3
     on t2.txnID = t3.txnID
group by t3.item;
```